# A problem with classes/selectors (HTML,PHP,CSS)

Tags: php, html, css, class, css-selectors

I have a problem with classes or selectors in HTML/PHP/CSS files.

I have an **index.html** in which I have some elements using some classes.

**Example**;

```
...
<**p** class="**asdasdasd**"> An example paragraph. <**/p**>
...
```

And I have a  **styles.css** in which I have some selectors to style my elements in **index.html**.

**Example**;

```
**.asdasdasd**{<br>
    color: white;<br>
    background-color: gray;<br>
    font-size: 23px;<br>
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;<br>
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;<br>
}
```

Whenever I try to change names of classes/selectors (*e.g.* **asdasdasd** to **qwertyuio**), elements start to use their old, default, classic styles.
What could be the reason for this?
How can I prevent this?

Thanks from now on to everyone who will try to help.

Comment: You can add another class `class="asdasdasd  qwertyuio"`

Comment: Could you put a complete example of an instance when you have changed the class names? It sounds like the only reasons could be either a typo or not all the classes changed.

Comment: cachine, order in the stylesheet, specificity, typo